# Can I run linux with Windows EFI partition or do I need to mount /boot to the EFI Partition?

Tags: linux

C trying to set up a dual-boot for windows and linux on my laptop. However, I was wondering if I was still required to mount /boot to the EFT partition if im dual booting.